# What are the axes of an ellipse within a rhombus?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

For a rhombus of x width and y height, what are the major and minor axes of the unique inscribed ellipse tangent to the midpoints of the rhombus's sides? Thank you.

Comment: 1. A given rhombus contains a one-parameter family of inscribed ellipses, so as stated your question appears not to be answerable. 2. In any event, could you please include the _entire question_ in the body rather than splitting information between the title and body (if that's what happened)?

Comment: Two remarks, 1) describing a rhombus is not as describing a rectangle. You need a supplementary (angular) information 2) There is not one ellipse inscribed in a rhombus but an infinity (think for example to a lozenge). But maybe you are thinking to the (unique) ellipse tangent to the sides in their midpoints. Is it that ?

Comment: You may have many solutions with variety of major and minor axes.

Comment: I understand now that did not know that in English, "rhombus" is synonymous to "lozenge". Thus are your $x$ and $y$ the lengthes of the diagonals ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $4a$ be the longest diagonal, and $4b$ be the shortest one (see figure with $a=2$, $b=\frac{3}{2}.)$

It is not difficult to show (see explanations below) that the equation of the inscribed ellipse in the rhombus that is tangent to it **in the midpoints of its sides** is:

$$\tag{1}\frac{b}{a}x^2+\frac{a}{b}y^2=2ab$$

Putting this in the equivalent standard form for the equation of an ellipse having coord. axes as its symmetry axes:

$$\frac{x^2}{(a\sqrt{2})^2}+\frac{y^2}{(b\sqrt{2})^2}=1$$

meaning that the looked-for half-axis are

$$A=a\sqrt{2} \ \ \text{and} \ \ B=b\sqrt{2}.$$

See figure below with $2a=4$, $2b=3$, $A=2\sqrt{2}\approx 2.83..$, $B=\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{2}\approx 2.12.$

Explanations for (1): First note the - expected - symmetry in $a$ and $b$.

Equation (1) is verified by midpoint $E(x=a, y=b)$ and more generaly by the four points $(x=\pm a, y=\pm b)$ (see figure).

Besides, the tangent equation to the ellipse in $(x_0,y_0)$ is

$$\tag{2}\frac{b}{a}xx_0+\frac{a}{b}yy_0=2ab.$$

Taking $x_0=a$, $y_0=b$ in (2) gives the equation $\frac{x}{a}+ \frac{y}{b}=1$ of straight line CD, as awaited.

[image]

Comment: Two very good answers for this question. I'm not sure it's fair, but I have selected the answer that correctly intuited the missing part of my question. I was, in fact, asking about the unique ellipse tangent to the rhombus's sides at their midpoints. Thank you both very much.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned by others, a given rhombus admits infinitely-many inscribed ellipses. Perhaps unexpectedly, there's an interesting way to construct the family. First, some algebra:

[image]

Suppose an origin-centered rhombus with vertices $P=(p,0)$ and $Q=(0,q)$ has an origin-centered (and axis-aligned) inscribed ellipse through $A = (a,0)$ and $B=(0,b)$. As line $\overleftrightarrow{PQ}$ only touches the ellipse once, there can be at exactly one common solution to their equations
$$\frac{x}{p} + \frac{y}{q} = 1 \qquad\text{and}\qquad \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$$
Eliminating $y$ from the above, and solving for $x$, gives
$$ x =  \frac{ap}{a^2q^2+b^2p^2}\left(a q^2 \pm b \sqrt{
  a^2 q^2 + b^2 p^2 - p^2 q^2} \right)$$
but, since there should be exactly one solution, we conclude that the discriminant must vanish:

$$a^2 q^2 + b^2 p^2 - p^2 q^2 = 0 \qquad\to\qquad \frac{a^2}{p^2} + \frac{b^2}{q^2} = 1 \tag{$\star$}$$

Observe that the second form of the equation in $(\star)$ says precisely that the point $K=(a,b)$ lies on the (axis-aligned) ellipse through the vertices of the rhombus:

[image]

Indeed, every point on the circumscribed ellipse gives rise to an inscribed ellipse:

[image]

Neat!

---

**Edit.** If, as OP later stated, the question is specifically about the ellipse tangent to the *midpoints* of the sides of the rhombus, then the solution is easy.

We leverage the fact that tangency, midpoint-ness, and ellipse-ness are *affinely-independent* notions. That is to say, they're preserved under various [affine transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation), in particular: scaling (aka stretching). The upshot here: *If we can solve this problem for a square, then we've solved the problem for all rhombi.* Of course, solving the problem for a square is easy:

[image]

For a square with diagonal-length $2s$, the radius of the circle inscribed in that square (and necessarily tangent at the midpoints of its sides) is clearly $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} s$. If we stretch the square into a rhombus with diagonal-lengths $2p$ and $2q$ ...

[image]

... then we correspondingly scale "horizontal" distances by $p/s$ and "vertical" distances by $q/s$. Consequently, the radii of the inscribed circle-turned-ellipse (which remains tangent at the midpoints of the sides of the square-turned-rhombus) are

> $$a = r \cdot \frac{p}{s} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}s\cdot\frac{p}{s} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} p \qquad\text{and}\qquad b = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}q$$

Comment: Thank you very much. I have worked my way through your equations and learned a good bit.

Comment: @Blue Remarkable solution.